# How to prove the Littlewood-Paley characterization of Holder norm?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-analysis, littlewood-paley-theory

Here our aim is to prove that the Holder norm
\begin{equation}
\|f\|_{\Lambda_\gamma}:=\|f\|_{L^{\infty}}+\sup _{x \neq y \in \mathbb{R}^n} \frac{|f(x)-f(y)|}{|x-y|^\gamma}
\end{equation}
is equivalent to
\begin{equation}
\|f\|_{\Lambda_\gamma} \approx\left\|P_{\leq 0} f\right\|_{L^{\infty}}+\sup_{k>0} 2^{k \gamma}\left\|P_k f\right\|_{L^{\infty}},
\end{equation}
where $P_k$ is the Littlewood-Paley projection. I am now stuck in the proof of
\begin{equation}
\|f\|_{L^{\infty}}+\sup _{x \neq y \in \mathbb{R}^n} \frac{|f(x)-f(y)|}{|x-y|^\gamma}
\lesssim \left\|P_{\leq 0} f\right\|_{L^{\infty}}+\sup_{k>0} 2^{k \gamma}\left\|P_k f\right\|_{L^{\infty}}.
\end{equation}
In fact, we let $f(x) = P_{\le 0} f+ \sum_{k>0} P_k f$. The previous one $P_{\le 0} f$ is easy to be controlled. As for $\sum_{k>0} P_k f$, we found that
\begin{align*}
\frac{|P_kf(x)-P_k f(y)|}{|x-y|^\gamma}
& \simeq \frac{|P_k^2f(x)-P_k^2 f(y)|}{|x-y|^\gamma} \\
& =\Big|  \int \frac{m_k (x-z) -m_k(y-z)}{|x-y|^\gamma} P_kf(z) dz \Big| \\
& = \Big|  \int \frac{｜m_k (x-z) -m_k(y-z)｜}{|x-y|^\gamma}  dz \Big| \cdot \| P_k f \|_\infty, 
\end{align*}
where $m_k(x)= 2^{kn} \phi (2^k x)$ and $\hat{\phi}$ is support on an annulus $1 \le |x| \le 4$. Then we see that
\begin{align*}
  \int \frac{｜m_k (x-z) -m_k(y-z)｜}{|x-y|^\gamma}  dz 
& = \int_{\mathbb{R}^N} \frac{｜m_k (z+h) -m_k(z)｜}{|h|^\gamma}  dz \\
& \lesssim |h|^{1-\gamma}\int_{\mathbb{R}^N} \int_0^1  |\nabla m_k(z+th)  dtdz \\
& \lesssim |h|^{1-\gamma} 2^{k}, \quad \text{where} h=y-x,
\end{align*}
moreover, we also have
\begin{align*}
  \int \frac{｜m_k (x-z) -m_k(y-z)｜}{|x-y|^\gamma}  dz 
& \lesssim |h|^{-\gamma},
\end{align*}
so we see that
\begin{align*}
  \int \frac{｜m_k (x-z) -m_k(y-z)｜}{|x-y|^\gamma}  dz 
& \lesssim 
\min\{|h|^{1-\gamma} 2^k, |h|^{-\gamma} \} \simeq 2^{k \gamma},
\end{align*}
hence we see that we can only get that
\begin{align*}
\frac{|P_kf(x)-P_k f(y)|}{|x-y|^\gamma}
& = \Big|  \int \frac{｜m_k (x-z) -m_k(y-z)｜}{|x-y|^\gamma}  dz \Big| \cdot \| P_k f \|_\infty \lesssim 2^{k \gamma} \| P_k f \|_\infty,
\end{align*}
but then we can only get that
\begin{align*}
\sup_{x\not = y}\frac{|\sum_{k>0} P_k f(x)- \sum_{k>0} P_k f(y)|}{|x-y|^\gamma}
\lesssim \sum_{k >0} 2^{k \gamma} \| P_k f \|_\infty,
\end{align*}
and we cannot further bound it by $\sup_{k > 0 }2^{k \gamma} \| P_k f \|_\infty$.

So I wonder is there any improvement about the proof? A simple idea is that I want to improve the estimate to
\begin{align*}
\frac{|P_kf(x)-P_k f(y)|}{|x-y|^\gamma}
& \lesssim 2^{k \gamma'} \| P_k f \|_\infty,
\end{align*}
for some $\gamma' < \gamma$. But roughly speaking, the above quotation term can be regarded as $D^\gamma P_k f(x)$, so it is almost equal to $2^{k \gamma} P_k(x)$, which I am a little confused.

Comment: From memory, there’s a proof of this in PDEs by Taylor which you may find helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow your proof, $$\sup_{h\ne 0}\frac{|\sum_{k>0}P_kf(x+h)-\sum_{k>0}P_kf(x)|}{|h|^\gamma} \le \sup_{h}\sum_{k>0} \min(|h|^{1-\gamma}2^k, |h|^{-\gamma})\Vert P_kf\Vert_\infty,$$ where one pick an $h$ uniformly for all coefficients $\min(|h|^{1-\gamma}2^k, |h|^{-\gamma})$. Then for a large $k$, this coefficient is far less than $2^{k\gamma}$. One can in fact show that $\sum_{k>0} \min(|h|^{1-\gamma}2^k2^{-k\gamma}, |h|^{-\gamma}2^{-k\gamma})$ is bounded.

Comment: That means using the first term in the minimum for the summation of the first few terms and using the second one for the summation of the rest. Nice proof!

Comment: Très bien! Thanks to Prof. Great Chushannn, who inspired me on this question! Follow this idea, it can be bounded by $(C_1 2^N h)^{1-\gamma} + ( C_2 2^N h)^{-\gamma}$ for some constants $C_1$ and $C_2$ and any $N$. We can easily see that it is bounded by picking N such that these two terms almost equal.